# File format not recognized error while installing CBLAS on a Ubuntu machine

Tags: lapack, blas, cblas

I need to install CBLAS on an Ubuntu 16.04.4 machine. The following values have been set in the `Makefile.in` file of CBLAS:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh

PLAT = LINUX

BLLIB = /home/ubuntu/BLAS-3.8.0/blas_LINUX.a
CBLIB = /home/ubuntu/CBLAS/lib/cblas_LINUX.a

CC = gcc
FC = gfortran
LOADER = $(FC)

CFLAGS = -O3 -DADD_ -fPIC
FFLAGS = -O3 -fPIC

ARCH = gcc
ARCHFLAGS = -shared -o
RANLIB = ranlib
```

However, while running the `make` command I run into following error:

`ranlib: /home/ubuntu/CBLAS/lib/cblas_LINUX.a: File format not recognized`

The following is the stack trace:

[image]

Can someone suggest how this can be resolved?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? The answer given does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**CBLAS shared libraries** : `sudo apt install libatlas3-base libatlas-base-dev`

`libatlas3-base` provides

```
/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3
/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3.0
/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3
/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3.0
/usr/lib/atlas-base/libatlas.so.3
/usr/lib/atlas-base/libatlas.so.3.0
/usr/lib/atlas-base/libcblas.so.3
/usr/lib/atlas-base/libcblas.so.3.0
/usr/lib/atlas-base/libf77blas.so.3
/usr/lib/atlas-base/libf77blas.so.3.0
/usr/lib/atlas-base/liblapack_atlas.so.3
/usr/lib/atlas-base/liblapack_atlas.so.3.0
/usr/lib/libatlas.so.3
/usr/lib/libcblas.so.3             ←  ←
/usr/lib/libf77blas.so.3
/usr/lib/liblapack_atlas.so.3
```

`libatlas-base-dev` provides

```
/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.a
/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so
/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.a
/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so
/usr/lib/atlas-base/libatlas.a
/usr/lib/atlas-base/libatlas.so
/usr/lib/atlas-base/libcblas.a
/usr/lib/atlas-base/libcblas.so
/usr/lib/atlas-base/libf77blas.a
/usr/lib/atlas-base/libf77blas.so
/usr/lib/atlas-base/liblapack_atlas.a
/usr/lib/atlas-base/liblapack_atlas.so
/usr/lib/libatlas.a
/usr/lib/libatlas.so
/usr/lib/libcblas.a
/usr/lib/libcblas.so               ←  ←
/usr/lib/libf77blas.a
/usr/lib/libf77blas.so
/usr/lib/liblapack_atlas.a
/usr/lib/liblapack_atlas.so
```

Comment: how do set BLLIB and CBLIB based on your answer?